# this.ИМЯ_ФУНКЦИИ is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть класс, в котором есть 3 функции. Две из них должны возвратить значение. Не получается вызвать функции getUsername(arg) и getTotal(arg) внутри функции getStats(callback). Получаю ошибку "TypeError: this.getUsername is not a function"

Но функция успешно выполняется в теле класса.

В чем причина не выполнения функций? Имена функций менял, не помогло. Выполняю на NodeJS.

```
const colors = require('colors');


function Stats(collection, group_id) {
  this.collection = collection;
  this.group_id = group_id;
  this.empty = {
    _id: null,
    usernames: [],
    titles: [],
    members: {
      total: [],
      joined: [],
      joined_by_link: [],
      added: [],
      leaved: [],
      kicked: []
    },
    admins: [],
    bots: [],
    group_pics: [],
    pins: [],
    full_chat_last_date: null
  };

  this.getUsername = function (group) {
    return null;
  };

  this.getTotal = function (group) {
    return null;
  };

  this.getStats = function (callback) {
    //делает запрос к таблице
    // если получает строку, заменяет информацию this.Stats
    // если нет, оставляет прежней

    this.collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, groups) {

      for (let group of groups) {
        if (group["_id"] == this.group_id) {

          //Вычислить значения для статов группы

          this.stats_light = {
            username: null,//this.getUsername(group), - тут не работает
            title: group.titles[group.titles.length-1].value,
            total: null,//this.getTotal(group), - тут не работает
            admins: group.admins[group.admins.length-1].value.length,
            bots: group.bots[group.bots.length-1].value.length
          }

          console.log(colors.yellow("callback"));
          callback(group, stats_light);
          return;
        }
      }

      console.log(colors.yellow("callback NOTHING"));
      callback(this.empty);
      return;

      if (err) console.log(colors.red(err));

    });
  };

  //------------------------------
  //Тут работает
  let e = this.getUsername(2);
  //------------------------------

}

exports.Stats = Stats;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри `function(err, groups) {` другой контекст.

```
var that = this;
this.collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, groups) {

  for (let group of groups) {
    if (group["_id"] == this.group_id) {

      //Вычислить значения для статов группы

      this.stats_light = {
        that.getUsername(group), // тут работает
```

Comment: Спасибо!  Почему так произошло?

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов Внутри `function(err, groups) {` другой контекст.